# OpenGL ES 2.0 SL writing out from fragment shader to texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, framebuffer, fragment-shader

Hopefully this is a really simple question.

How to write out to a texture attached to framebuffer from within a fragment shader. I assume it is just gl_FragColor, am I suppose to define/use a different variable, like gl_Data[0]?

Frag Shader:

```
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
        uniform sampler2D displayTexture;
        void main() {
          gl_FragColor = texture2D(displayTexture, vTextureCoord);
        }
```

This question is not how to setup a texture for writing to, just how to write out from within the fragment shader. I just want to make sure I have this piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Yes, it should be the same output. When you switch to the display buffer, you will need to change the shader program if you have different uniforms/processing needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to assume correct. All the drawing code should be the same drawing to render buffer as to an attached texture, even shaders.

Comment: Could there be something strange going on with the texture format attacched to the FBO? Like I define some config attribs in EGL as RGBA8, but there is no option for that attaching the texture to the FBO, just RGBA4, so is the conversion done automatically or is this something that is going to kill me?

Comment: The conversion might kill you. You should be able to make it RGBA8. Where do you insert this parameter? It might be just RGB as a default. Also if I remember correctly the openGL will internally always work with RGBA8 and will scale other formats when transferring data: RGBA4 will be scaled x2 to RGBA8 but the data you push to texture must be 16-bit (being the part that kills you).

Comment: `glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA,       rain.width, rain.height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA,       GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, juliaTexBuff)` supposedly it always works with GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, so I don't think that is the part that is killing me. This question is complete, and that question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149605/load-uniform-matrix-1104-gl-invalid-operation-android-opengles-2-0)

Comment: Since you are attaching this buffer the relevant parameters are GLES20.GL_RGBA. You do not even need "juliaTexBuff" you can send it as NULL unless you begin the buffer with some data but clearing the frame buffer will run over those data. If you do use it (or sub image) then that data buffer should correspond to GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 values.

Comment: How do you know about Julia? Are you SPYING ON ME? oh, ic, never mind.  What do you mean juliaTexBuff can be null? This might be important. So what you are saying is when swapping between two textures (read/write) call `glTexImage2D()` after each `glBindTexture()` (during initiation) so that both textures are attached as a TexImage2D, and the `intBuff` is NOT the connection point?

Comment: WOW you kick soooooo much ***! I would have spent a lifetime trying to figure out that bug if you hadn't added that note.