# Load Uniform Matrix 1104 GL_Invalid_Operation Android OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, render-to-texture

I am working on implementing rendering to texture on Android 4.3+ (OpenGLES 2.0)

I am getting the following error in my `DrawFrame()` method:

```
01-15 13:40:07.545: W/Adreno-ES20(23709): <__load_uniform_matrix:1104>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
01-15 13:40:07.545: E/com.hpp.STextureRender(23709): glDrawArrays: glError 1282
01-15 13:40:07.545: D/io.hpp.CaptureManager(23709): Error encountered in drawFrame = glDrawArrays: glError 1282
01-15 13:40:07.545: W/System.err(23709): java.lang.RuntimeException: glDrawArrays: glError 1282
01-15 13:40:07.545: W/System.err(23709):    at com.hpp.openGL.STextureRender.checkGlError(STextureRender.java:524)
01-15 13:40:07.545: W/System.err(23709):    at com.hpp.openGL.STextureRender.drawFrame(STextureRender.java:316)
01-15 13:40:07.545: W/System.err(23709):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.openGL.MyGLRenderer.drawFrame(MyGLRenderer.java:286)
01-15 13:40:07.545: W/System.err(23709):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager.drawFrame(CaptureManager.java:446)
01-15 13:40:07.545: W/System.err(23709):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager.access$7(CaptureManager.java:444)
01-15 13:40:07.555: W/System.err(23709):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager$6.run(CaptureManager.java:278)
01-15 13:40:07.555: W/System.err(23709):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1463)
01-15 13:40:07.555: W/System.err(23709):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Could the problem stem from setting up `EGL14.eglChooseConfig(mEGLDisplay, configsAttribs, 0, configs, 0, configs.length, numConfigs, 0);` with

```
private int[] version, configsAttribs = {
        EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1,
        EGL14.EGL_NONE
```

But using the following texture connected to the FBO

```
    // generate the textures
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, rain.width, rain.height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, juliaTexBuff);
```

Notice the discrepency of RGBA4444 as opposed to RGBA8888 in EGL?

Comment: No, that cannot be your problem. RGBA4444 is the only ***guaranteed*** color-renderable RGBA format in OpenGL ES 2.0. If you are using an FBO, that is the safest RGBA format you could use and you are required to match the internal format with the pixel transfer format in GLES. Your default framebuffer's pixel format has nothing to do with the format of your FBO. If you are concerned about your FBO, then call `glCheckFramebufferStatus (...)`; the thing is, if this were your problem a compliant GL implementation would generate `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION` and not `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I didn't think that was the problem, but if you look at my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146060/render-buffer-generating-gl-invalid-operation-error-android-opengl-es-2-0) I thought this may be the problem. basically when I call `glBindFrameBuffer` before `glUseProgram` I get this error. In any case I am getting all zeros on the `intbuffer` attached to the texture that is attached to the FBO. But when I write out to display it displays fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was during loading a uniform variable before calling glUseProgram. If I put the call after the block that contained glGetUniform4fv() it obviously fails because it doesn't know where the uniform is because the program is loaded.